# How to solve a system of two polynomial equations?

Tags: equation, polynomials

I have two equations:

```
(x-6)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 6^2
(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 3^2
```

I subtracted the 2nd equation from the 1st and got the answer. However, I want to find `x` and `y` from the set of equations using any programming language. Can anybody help to get the source code for this?

Comment: If you want to solve mathematical equations symbolically like this, you could use e.g. [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/) or [Julia](https://julialang.org/). You could also check out [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com/) which solves these sort of things online.

Comment: I want the source code for the problem, not answers.

Comment: All of them, except from wolfram alpha, are programming languages. I've made an answer for you with source codes in some of these languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve mathematical equations symbolically like this, there are many programming languages and softwares available:

- [Julia](https://julialang.org/) (free)
- [Sympy](https://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html) (python library - free)
- [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) (paid)
- [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/) (paid)
- ([Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com/) which is just a solver online. (freemium))

Here are some "source code" as you requested:

#### [`sympy`](https://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html#equation-solving):

```
import sympy as sp
x=sp.Symbol('x')
y=sp.Symbol('y')
print(sp.solve([(x-6)**2+(y-2)**2-6**2, (x-2)**2+(y-2)**2-3**2], [x, y]))
```

### Mathematica:

```
FullSimplify[Solve[{(x - 6)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 6^2, (x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 3^2}, {x, y}]]
```

Mathematica also has it's own [SE site here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Just for the sake of examples: here is a [wolfram alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-6)%5E2%2B(y-2)%5E2%3D6%5E2,+(x-2)%5E2%2B(y-2)%5E2%3D3%5E2)

Comment: Is this implementable in java?

Comment: @muhammeduk I'm sorry, but I don't know Java. Also you didn't ask anything about java. You said **any** programming language. So I provided 3 suggestions for languages, two source code examples and an online solver :)

Comment: Yes. That was my mistake, I expected something in java or c or c++

Comment: Take a look at [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/). It's a C-library (written purely in C) and with open available source.